# logrotate not compressing files

Tags: linux, centos, logs, logrotate, troubleshooting

I'm having issues with logrotate as it does not compress files.
We migrated from Centos 7 to Alma linux and since it has not worked.
I'm trying to get logrotate to rotate and compress log files from /var/log/cisco.
Logrotate successfully rotates the log and appends date to file names.
Here's the config from /etc/logrotate.d/cisco_syslog

```
/var/log/cisco/* {
notifempty
weekly
olddir old
rotate 12
compress
create
sharedscripts
postrotate
/bin/kill -HUP `cat /var/run/syslogd.pid 2> /dev/null` 2> /dev/null || true
    /usr/bin/systemctl restart tail_aggregate.service 2> /dev/null
endscript }
```

Error message from /var/log/messages

```
Feb 13 03:50:40 management logrotate: ALERT exited abnormally with [1]
```

When I run logrotate in debug like this

```
logrotate -d -v /etc/logrotate.d/cisco_syslog --force
```

It successfully tries to compress files

```
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
compressing log with: /bin/gzip
```

gzip is installed and I'm able to manually compress files.

Edit:
Output of sestatus

```
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

Output of ausearch -ts today -m avc -i

```
<no matches>
```

Output of ls -laZ /var/log/cisco

[image: output]

Filenames are hidden for security reason.

Output of /etc/logrotate.conf

```
# see "man logrotate" for details
# rotate log files weekly
weekly

# keep 4 weeks worth of backlogs
rotate 4

# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
create

# use date as a suffix of the rotated file
dateext

# uncomment this if you want your log files compressed
compress

# RPM packages drop log rotation information into this              directory
include /etc/logrotate.d

# system-specific logs may be also be configured here.
```

Logrotate version

```
logrotate 3.14.0
```

Comment: Append `|| true` to the second line of your postrotate script

Comment: @roaima how does that solve the compressing issue?

Comment: Also, post output of `sestatus`, `ausearch -ts today -m avc -i`, and `ls -laZ /var/log/cisco`.

Comment: You're getting an ALERT in the message log. The only reason I can see that being triggered is if part of your `postrotate` script is failing. I've not put it as an answer (yet) because I don't know for sure it'll solve your issue

Comment: @Edward see updated post.

Comment: And what about `/var/log/cisco/old`? Don't you see the compressed files there?

Comment: @aviro no, that's the issue. Logrotate isn't compressing the files.

Comment: When did you reinstall the machine? Notice it runs on a weekly basis. Is it possible you reinstalled it less than a week ago?

Comment: Can you show us whatever global options you'd have defined in something like `/etc/logrotate.conf`?

Comment: @aviro we installed it before christmas. Logrotate is rotating but not compressing.

Comment: @parttimeturtle see updated post.